# Weird behavior of BigQuery for default values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to have default values populated for the columns where there are null values in BigQuery.

Example:
We have tables `test_1` and `test_2`, each with two columns `a` and `b`.
The target table `test_2` has DDL set to populate default value of 100 for the column `b` if the value is `NULL`.

It populates default value if we insert values using an insert statement:

```
Insert into `******.***STG_REFRESH_UAT.test`(a) values('2');
```

However, it does not populate default value if we select data from a table and insert it:

```
insert into `******.***STG_REFRESH_UAT.test1`(a,b) (Select * from `******.***STG_REFRESH_UAT.test`)
```

Comment: Can you show the schema and a preview of ******.***STG_REFRESH_UAT.test.

Answer (score 1):

*Default value* works where the column with default value is not specified or omitted when populating a table. For example,

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE `test` (
  a INT64,
  b INT64 DEFAULT 100
);
-- `b` column is not specified
INSERT INTO `test` (a) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `test` (a) (SELECT 2 AS a);
-- `b` column is specified, but with explicit `DEFAULT` value
INSERT INTO `test` (a, b) VALUES (3, DEFAULT);

SELECT * FROM `test`;
+-----+---+-----+
| row | a |  b  |
+-----+---+-----+
|   1 | 1 | 100 |
|   2 | 3 | 100 |
|   3 | 2 | 100 |
+-----+---+-----+
```

> insert into `＊＊.＊STG_REFRESH_UAT.test1`(a,b) (Select * from `＊＊.＊STG_REFRESH_UAT.test`)

But your second query specfies `b` column explicitly in order to get a value from underlying table whether it's a `null` or non-null value.

```sql
-- `select *` is expanded to `select a, b`.
insert into `STG_REFRESH_UAT.test` (a, b) (select a, b from `STG_REFRESH_UATtest`)
```

> to populate default value of `100` for the column `b` if the value is `NULL`.

If you didn't intend whole `b` column to be a default value, you need only to handle `null` value in `b` column using `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE` function.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE `test` (
  a INT64,
  b INT64 DEFAULT 100
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE `test1` AS (
  SELECT 10 AS a, 200 AS b UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 AS a, null AS b
);
-- *100* is a default value of `b` column
INSERT INTO `test` (SELECT a, IFNULL(b, 100) FROM `test1`);

SELECT * FROM `test`;
+-----+----+-----+
| row | a  |  b  |
+-----+----+-----+
|   1 | 10 | 200 |
|   2 | 20 | 100 |
+-----+----+-----+
```